# Aligning a asp:Button to to the right of asp:Wizard's Next Button

Tags: asp.net, css, alignment

Coding Platform: ASP.NET C#
Controls Used: asp:Wizard and asp:Button

I have a asp:Wizard and when it renders it have Previous and Next Buttons
I would like to place a button to the right of Next Button.
Now that button is being rendered below asp:Wizard Control.
Any method to accomplish it?

Update: I am not using StartNavigationTemplate, StepNavigationTemplate and FinishNavigationTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the Wizard control, but that's probably more effort than it's worth.

If you want to get a similar effect and you're not tied to the Wizard, you can abandon the Wizard control and use a [MultiView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/multiview.aspx) instead.  If you do, you need to control the flow programatically yourself (assign a variable to track the current index, create previous and next buttons, adjust the current index, etc).

It's a little more work, but you get better control.  (It's like using a Repeater vs. a GridView.  With a Gridview you can only do tables.  With a Repeater, you can do tables, but it's a bit more work, or you can do something completely different.)

I like [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/184406100;jsessionid=XOVBSEFHIIGGFQE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN) for explaining the similarity.

Comment: its a re-work on some other guys code. So what i basically want is either a quick solution or just close the whole thing as not possible within the time frame [:)]

Comment: Actually, it's pretty quick work to convert from the Wizard to a MultiView, since the Wizard uses the MultiView internally.  The article I linked to should get yo going.  I've done it myself, in less than an hour.  the number of steps doesn't really matter, since the main modifications you'd be making is adding your own control of the navigation.  A next button works the same with 5 or 500 steps in the wizard.  I'd say give it a shot and see how it works, and if it starts getting hairy, back out to the current version.  Good luck!